# How to display ' instead of &#39; in GSP

Tags: grails, gsp

I have an array like this :
['19 08 2015', '21 08 2015', '26 08 2015']

but in the gsp file it shows as :

```
[&#39;19 08 2015&#39;, &#39;21 08 2015&#39;, &#39;26 08 2015&#39;]
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

It's needed in the head section for the enabled_dates

```
$('#dateSelect').Zebra_DatePicker({

                 format:'d-m-Y',
                 disabled_dates:['* * 2015'],
                 enabled_dates:
```

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: What is the rest of the gsp code that uses the array?

Comment: Did you tried `<%@ page defaultCodec="none" %>` ?

Comment: @yat That worked!! Thanks!